# Pandas datetime formats

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling with pandas datetime formats. My dataset is as follows (dates are as type object):

```
+--------+------------+----------+---------------------------+---------------------+
|        | event_id_x | payback  | event_starts_utc_datetime |      dtScraped      |
+--------+------------+----------+---------------------------+---------------------+
|  80325 | 1004179030 | 0.980840 | 2017-09-13 20:45:03.888   | 2017-09-06 17:06:32 |
| 104592 | 1004179030 | 0.980840 | 2017-09-13 20:45:03.888   | 2017-09-06 19:23:56 |
| 261304 | 1004179030 | 0.980840 | 2017-09-13 20:45:03.888   | 2017-09-07 06:21:47 |
| 657433 | 1004179030 | 0.980840 | 2017-09-13 20:45:03.888   | 2017-09-08 13:06:05 |
| 661013 | 1004179030 | 0.979975 | 2017-09-13 20:45:03.888   | 2017-09-11 09:04:15 |
+--------+------------+----------+---------------------------+---------------------+
```

I wanted to pass event_starts_utc_datetime and dtScraped to datetime, however the following returns "ValueError: time data 'event_starts_utc_datetime' doesn't match format specified"

```
pinny_payback["event_starts_utc_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(["event_starts_utc_datetime"], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Could you please assist on this?

Comment: I cut and pasted one of your `event_starts_utc_datetime` fields into your code, and it did not return an error for me... is there a blank character in there somewhere? `pd.dtypes` shows `datetime64[ns]` as well.

Comment: Now it returned this: "error: redefinition of group name 'm' as group 7; was group 2 at position 160"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code to create your dummy df. I modified it to use commas and `pd.read_clipboard`.

```
"""
id,event_id_x,payback,event_starts_utc_datetime,dtScraped
80325,1004179030,0.980840,2017-09-13 20:45:03.888,2017-09-06 17:06:32
104592,1004179030,0.980840,2017-09-13 20:45:03.888,2017-09-06 19:23:56
261304,1004179030,0.980840,2017-09-13 20:45:03.888,2017-09-07 06:21:47
657433,1004179030,0.980840,2017-09-13 20:45:03.888,2017-09-08 13:06:05
661013,1004179030,0.979975,2017-09-13 20:45:03.888,2017-09-11 09:04:15
"""

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep = ',')

df['event_starts_utc_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_starts_utc_datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

print(df.dtypes)

df
```

I suspect your error may have just been not including the dataframe name within your `pd.to_datetime()` statement...

Output:

```
id                                    int64
event_id_x                            int64
payback                             float64
event_starts_utc_datetime    datetime64[ns]
dtScraped                            object
dtype: object
```

Comment: "I suspect your error may have just been not including the dataframe name within your pd.to_datetime() statement..." that's absolutely correct. Such a dumb error! Thanks so much